# delete row in mysql having primary key as varchar

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

I am trying to delete row from table demo where the primary keys are playername and country.Both of them are of type varchar having length 32 .Other columns are category (varchar 32 length) and price (int ). I have tried all of the below query to delete a row but unable in every case. Can anyone show me right way to do this.Thanks in advance.
Tried queries:

```
DELETE FROM demo WHERE Pname like 'shakib' and country like 'bangladesh'
DELETE FROM demo WHERE `Pname` like 'shakib' and `country` like 'bangladesh'
DELETE FROM `demo` WHERE `Pname` like 'shakib' and `country` like 'bangladesh'
DELETE FROM `demo` WHERE `Pname`='shakib' and `country`='bangladesh'
DELETE FROM `demo` WHERE `Pname`="shakib" and `country`="bangladesh"
```

Comment: Show some sample data,you probably need wildcards

Comment: Column is playername or Pname?

Comment: table data example : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F9C34605B8C6A3D2!12672&authkey=!ACFwpz9v9frK_ns&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG  @Mihai

Comment: column name is Pname @EatPeanutButter

Comment: Whenever you use LIKE, you need to include wildcard characters in the string literal to get it to actually match partial strings.  Try rewriting the first query as `DELETE FROM demo WHERE Pname like '%shakib%' and country like '%bangladesh%'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot .It worked .Finally got the deletion query going .:)..@EatPeanutButter